# R# and StyleCop

Tags: resharper, stylecop

I recently installed R# 6, in my previous version of R# I could disable StyleCop when editing old files by selecting options and disabling the StyleCop plugin. I can't find the option for this in R# 6, it's really annoying when opening an old file that had loads of violations (it really distracts me from the code).

Does anyone know where the option to disable plugin in R# 6 is?

Thanks,
Gareth.

**EDIT:**

Just to confirm, my previous version was 4.5, and to turn off StyleCop it was Resharper -> Plugins -> Then uncheck StyleCop...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dialog with the Plugins has moved to the Resharper Options.

Resharper -> Options -> [Environment - Plugins]